# M2DOC - how to get parameter in Java service

Tags: m2doc

I wrote a Java Service that I call like this in M2DOC my template :

```
{m:for pc | self.eAllContents(pa::PhysicalComponent)->select(p|p.name.equalsIgnoreCase('the parameter')).eAllContents(pa::PhysicalComponent)}
 {m:pc.ServerTable()}
 {m:endfor}
```

because I don't know how to get "the parameter" in my java Service.

In fact I would like to call my Java service like this :

```
{m:for pc | self.eAllContents(pa::PhysicalComponent)}
 {m:pc.ServerTable()}
 {m:endfor}
```

and get all PhysicalComponent with name 'the parameter' in the Java Service and not in the template.

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write a Java service for [M2Doc](http://www.m2doc.org/)/[AQL](https://www.eclipse.org/acceleo/documentation/aql.html) (the query language used by M2Doc) the Java method should have at least one parameter but you can add more. You Java method should look like this:

```
public SomeReturnType serverTable(PhysicalComponent component, String parameter) {
  ...
}
```

you can then call it like this in your template :

```
{m:pc.serverTable('the parameter')}
```